# No such file or directory in SSH

Tags: command-line

```
hadoopmaster@dhruvhadoop1:~$ cat /home/hadoopmaster/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopmaster/.ssh/authorized_keys
hadoopmaster@dhruvhadoop1:~$ chmod 600 authorized_keys
chmod: cannot access ‘authorized_keys’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `stat home/hadoopmaster/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Please [edit] your post (and use [correct formatting](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)) and i) ask an actual question; ii) explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: provide details to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be attempting to change the permissions of `/home/hadoopmaster/.ssh/authorized_keys`. If so, you need to use the right path, not just the file name. Try again with:

```
chmod 600 /home/hadoopmaster/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

or

```
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

or

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```